# Create a class that derives from string builder to append any number of strings

Tags: c#

i want to create a class that derives from string builder to append any number of strings.
 My Program should allow the user input their own number of strings.

i am able to append strings in the programmatically but i want the user of the winforms program to be able to input his custom strings in the program

example usage:

```
// Format Post Data

StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
postData.Append("dst");
postData.Append("&popup=true");
postData.Append(String.Format("&username={0}", USERNAME_Validate1));// reads username from username textbox
postData.Append(String.Format("&password={0}", PASSWORD_Validate1));// reads password from password textbox

//Write Post Data To Server

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    writer.Write(postData);
```

Comment: Read the docs, try something. If you get stuck, come back to stackoverflow.com and ask a specific question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "append any number of strings"? What would you be able to do with your class, that you cannot do with `StringBuilder`?

Comment: i am able to append strings in the programmatically but i want the user of the winforms program to be able to input his custom strings in the program

Comment: You're trying to build POST data by slapping strings together? Why? Are you sure your data is never going to require proper encoding/escaping etc.? And what exactly is it that `StringBuilder` (and `string.Format`) lack? You're already "appending any number of strings".

Comment: [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) is `sealed` so it cannot be inherited

Comment: How Can i do this without inheriting from string builder?

Comment: Sounds more like you want to create a class that **uses** a `StringBuilder` (internally).

Comment: [Extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb383977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) FTW!

Comment: @UweKeim -- yeah, that was the first thought reading the question. Something like `public static class StringBuilderExtension{ public static StringBuilder AppendAll(this StringBuilder stringBuilder, params string[] items) { foreach(var item in items){ stringBuilder.Append(item); } return stringBuilder; }}` -- but that doesn't seem to be what OP wants.

Comment: @corak -- that code is exactly what i want thanx

Comment: @Corak Please copy your comment to an answer so that the OP can accept it and other people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@corak -- that code is exactly what i want thanx

```
public static class StringBuilderExtension {
    public static StringBuilder AppendAll(
        this StringBuilder stringBuilder,
        params string[] items
    ) {
        foreach(var item in items) {
            stringBuilder.Append(item);
        }
        return stringBuilder;
    }
}
```